# Website log in auto fill

Tags: c#, html, autofill

I want to auto fill in a web page and then submit the data in C#.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Like pythons' mechanize but for C#. It allows you to fill in POST forms and then submit the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to fake a POST HTTP-Request to the webserver. You will need the following classes:
[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx). The POST data will be the values for the form fields, to find out the POST request a browser sends out, have a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Another way could be the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Comment: Also take a look at Fiddler, very nice for viewing/debugging HTTP(S) traffic between the web browser and server. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically or inside of an actual browser window?  If the latter, try [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).